# Flutter modal bottom sheet the little black thing

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

my question might sound a bit off but how to make this thing ? i'am not sure what is called i'm sorry
[image]

Comment: The drag handle, a feature introduced in Material 3, will be available in Flutter bottom sheet by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a widget or combination of widgets. You can use the code below and then position it at that point

```
SizedBox(
width 40,
child: Divider(height: 3, thickness: 3,color: Colors.grey),
),
```

That is the quickest solution I could come up with.
Alternatively you can use a **Row()** then look for such a line icon and have it as the child. Of course setting the crossAxis to center

Answer (score 1):

I think we can call it "anchor point"?

Code to create one with nice border radius:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
  child: Container(
    height: 5,
    width: 80,
    decoration:
    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[300], borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
  ))
```